# How to stringify new Map()?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const x = new Map([['key', 'value']])
```

Now, I want to stringify this. I used the following:

```
JSON.stringify(x)
```

...which gave me an empty object.

How do you actually perform the stringification on `new Map()`? Is it something like you first turn it into an object and then stringify it?

I am expecting the output to be `{"key": "value"}`.

Comment: try JSON.stringify([...x])

Comment: @ThanveerShah I thought `Map` & `Object` are similar so I was expecting object sort of output.

Comment: Yes they are similar

Answer (score 3):

You could get the array from the map and stringify the result.

```js
const x = new Map([['key', 'value']])

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(x)));
```

Comment: I was expecting output to be `{"key": "value"}` as `Object` and `Map` are similar. Isn't this how it should be or not?

Comment: @Sanjay  try -> `[...m.entries()].reduce((a, v) => (a[v[0]] = v[1],a), {});`

Comment: @Keith So you've got to loop and stuff everytime. This sucks but thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: it is exactly in the format, you can take it as whole map for the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access direct value then you can use this in loop.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(x.get('key')));
```